# fail to attach eBPF blob

Tags: linux-kernel, bpf, ebpf

I've just compiled BPF examples from kernel `tools/testing/selftests/bpf` and tried to load as explained in http://cilium.readthedocs.io/en/v0.10/bpf/:

```
% tc filter add dev enp0s1 ingress bpf \
    object-file ./net-next.git/tools/testing/selftests/bpf/sockmap_parse_prog.o \
    section sk_skb1 verbose 
Program section 'sk_skb1' not found in ELF file!
Error fetching program/map!
```

This happens on Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS with kernel 4.4.0-98, `llvm` and `clang` of version 3.8 installed from packages, `iproute2` is the latest from github.

I suspect I'm running into some toolchain/kernel version/features mismatch.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why tc complains. On my setup, with a similar command, the program loads. Still, here are some hints:

- I *think* the problem might come, as you suggest, from some incompatibility between kernel headers version and iproute2, and that some relocation fails to occur, although on a quick investigation I did not find exactly why it refuses to load the section. On my side I'm using clang-3.8, latest iproute2, but also the latest kernel (some commit close to 4.14).
- If you manage to load the section somehow, I believe you would still encounter problems when trying to attach the program in the kernel. The feature called “[direct packet access](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=969bf05eb3cedd5a8d4b7c346a85c2ede87a6d6d)” is only present on [kernels 4.7 and higher](https://github.com/iovisor/bcc/blob/master/docs/kernel-versions.md#main-features). This is what makes you able to use `skb->data` and `skb->data_end` in your programs.
- Then as a side note, this program `sockmap_parse_prog.c` is not meant to be used with tc. It is supposed to be attached directly to a socket (search for `SOCKMAP_PARSE_PROG` in file `test_maps.c` in the same directory to see how it is loaded there). Technically this does not prevent one to attach the program as a tc filter, but it will probably not work as expected. In particular, the value returned from the program will probably not have a meaning that tc classifier hook will understand.

So I would advise to try with a recent kernel, and to see if you have more success. Alternatively, try compiling and running the examples that you can find in your own kernel sources. Good luck!

Comment: thanks for your comments. I will have to try build and install latest kernel/ Could you advise what TC-friendly bpf example I should try instead of `sockmap_parse_prog.c` ?

Comment: Alternatively, you could install a VM with a recent distro, I think Ubuntu 17.04 for example has kernel 4.8? For the samples, maybe you could start by running `samples/bpf/parse_simple.c`, it's a very basic program that seems to drop UDP packets with a given destination port number. Note you also have other samples under `tools/testing/selftests/bpf`. You can grep for `TC_ACT_` return codes to find programs that were written for tc.